ECS Fargate Service stopped giving metrics while all tasks stayed healthy and running
We are running an ECS Cluster with a service running 2 tasks.
At 10:05 the service stopped showing any metrics.
At 13:45 I forced the service to restart and at that point the service gave metrics again.

All tasks stayed in a running state
All tasks stayed healthy
Logs keep going during the "outages"
I couldn't access the app but the logs show, some people were able to get in the app
Tasks were stable since the day before.
Some API calls keep working
Some API give a 504 Gateway timeout
Health endpoint returns 504 but Load balancer still gives Healthy

Does anyone have an idea why this could have happened?



I've seen that happen once before. I think it's due to some internal outage in AWS, related to the CloudWatch service or something. You would have to open an AWS support ticket to get any actual information on the reason behind this. Nobody here is going to be able to look into that for you.

I don't think it is an AWS issue. We had it again in the evening, POST calls keep working, but GET calls return a 504 Gateway timeout. Strangely our Health endpoint also returns a 504 but the ELB still says everything is healthy

If AWS Fargate stops reporting CPU utilization to CloudWatch, I don't see how that could be anything other than an AWS issue. How could it possibly be anything else?
